# How to see the algorithm of the defaultm projection

Tags: matlab

I'm doing a research about map projections. I use this script:

```
koordinat = [0 102;...
         0 103.5;...
        -1 103.5;...
        -1 102];
lat = koordinat(:,1);
lon = koordinat(:,2);  
mstruct = defaultm('utm');
mstruct.geoid = referenceEllipsoid('wgs84','meters');
mstruct.zone = utmzone(koordinat);
mstruct = defaultm(mstruct);
[x,y] = mfwdtran (mstruct,lat,lon);
format long g
luas = polyarea(x,y)
```

By using the "defaultm" and "mfwdtran" function, I can calculate the projected coordinate. Buut, my fellow researcher is feeling doubtful about these 2 Matlab functions. Do you know how to see the script of these two functions? 
I already opened the defaultm.m and mfwdtran.m, but I didn't see anything like an m-file from mathworks.com called "deg2utm.m". 
Any suggestion will helps.

Thank you

Comment: You can't, they are owned by Mathworks.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Unfortunately, is there any alternative?

Comment: Writing you own